# EF 7 Foreign key association to Identity User

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I want to have an entity (`Customer`) that NEEDS/MUST be an `ApplicationUser` but that it doesn't expose the user (`ApplicationUser`) properties. The idea is to have my `Customer` entity free from user properties but an id (`CustomerId`) that happens to be the `UserId`. I was thinking about inheritance but that will give me visibility on all the identity (`ApplicationUser`) properties which is not desired.

Having

```
ApplicationUser : Identity
```

and

```
Customer {
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

another thinking was using fluent api to make that `CustomerId` property as a ForeignKey to `UserId` on the User table but I don't know how to do it.

using fluent api, how can I make `CustomerId` a foreign key to `ApplicationUser.UserId` and that is also required ?

Is this a correct approach to the issue, or is there any other way to solve this that I'm not seeing ?

Any opinion is welcome

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "Must be a User" (when you aren't exposing any user properties). What is the purpose of the entity? In other words, what will you do with a UserId if you don't have any other properties to get/set on it?

Comment: The user login register, etc is managed by Identity. In the table it will have those other properties but I don't want them to be visible on Customer entity (object) only the CustomerId which is the same as the UserId.

Comment: What is your compelling reason to want to do this? On the face if it this does not seem like a good idea. Now you can't be a customer unless you are a user, and a customer could never have multiple users/log in identities.

Comment: I want customers to be users, and also have other entities to be users too, like manager. and I don't need nor want that a customer had many login identities. Also I want that when I'm workingin code with customer I don't see the last login date, etc.

Comment: Create an explicit implementation of the IIdentity inteface on the Customer entity.  Or create an interface for the ApplicationUser - IApplicationUser which inherits IIdentity and then implement that interface explicitly on the Customer entity

Comment: actually sounds like you need one to zero or one, as a user doens't have to be a customer if I'm reading the comments correctly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToOptional